# How is the number 65 stored in memory in bits?

Tags: memory, binary, bit

For reference - 65 is represented as 00110110 00110101 when stored in memory. Can someone share the exact step by step process on how 65 was converted to these specific 1s and 0s when stored in memory?

As a side note -

I'm trying to disambiguate my understanding from 65's conversion to binary, which is represented by character A, which is 01000001

Answer (score 1):

00110110 and 00110101 are [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) codes for the characters “6” and “5”. The codes are largely arbitrary, so there is not a mathematical conversion from 65 to these codes, except that the codes for the digits “0” to “9” are consecutive, so the code for “6” is six more than the code for “0” (00110000, or 48 in decimal).

65 in binary is indeed 01000001, but this is not **the** code for the character “A”. It is only **a** code for the character “A”. There encodings other than ASCII, such as EBCDIC. (The EBCDIC code for “A” is 11000001, or 193 in decimal.)

Comment: Thanks. To be super clear, say I store 65 in memory using a simple C program. So what gets stored in heap is 2 bytes, 1 byte has 00110110 and the other byte has 00110101. 

However, when I store 'A' in the same heap, what gets stored is 100 0001? 
Also, even though 6 and 5 itself can be represented in binary, from memory storage perspective, it has no utility whatsoever. 

Is my understanding correct?